# Powershell export-csv SQL User rights

Tags: sql-server, powershell, export-to-csv

sorry for the question but i have a problem to export to csv.
I found this useful script to have all userrights on the databases but I dont know how to export it to csv like: **SQL Instance, Login, Permissions**

I tried with write-output but nothing good.
Thanks ins advance for your help

```
Function GetDBUserInfo($Dbase)  
 {  
  if ($dbase.status -eq "Normal")  
   {$users = $Dbase.users | where {$_.login -eq $SQLLogin.name}
     foreach ($u in $users)  
     {  
       if ($u)  
         {    
           $DBRoles = $u.enumroles()   
           foreach ($role in $DBRoles) {
           if ($role -eq "db_owner") {
           write-host $role "on"$Dbase.name -foregroundcolor "red" 
           }
           else { 
           write-host $role "on"$Dbase.name
           }
           } 

         foreach($perm in $Dbase.EnumObjectPermissions($u.Name)){
         write-host  $perm.permissionstate $perm.permissiontype "on" $perm.objectname "in" $DBase.name } 
      }  
    } 
   }  

 }  

 [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null  

 foreach ($SQLsvr in get-content "path to instace list")
 {    
   $svr = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $SQLsvr   
   write-host "==============================================================================" 
   $svr.name
   $SQLLogins = $svr.logins 

   foreach ($SQLLogin in $SQLLogins)  
    {  

    write-host    "Login          : " $SQLLogin.name     

     if ($SQLLogin.EnumDatabaseMappings())  
       {write-host "Permissions:"
       foreach ( $DB in $svr.Databases)   
         {   
         GetDBUserInfo($DB)              
         }          
       }
     Else  
       {write-host "Permissions: None"
       }   
     write-host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" 
     } 
    }
```

Comment: Did you try [export-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)?

Comment: yes but i got the error with InputObject

Comment: Can you post an example of what you tried with export-csv, and the exact error text you received?

Comment: When I simply put at the end export-csv -Path "c:\...." -NoTypeInformation i get an
```cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject: 
```

Comment: `Write-Host` only writes to the console (or information stream). It is not used for standard output. You need to use `Write-Output` or simply execute the command and capture its output. Then you can pipe that into `Export-Csv`.

Comment: what format do you want the csv to have?  do you want a separate file per sqllogin?  Or one file with a row per sqllogin, and each row has columns with nested comma-delimited values for roles, permissions, etc.?